# SaveFileDialog does not open in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a SaveFileDialog to save file from database.

It works fine until I host the website on IIS. Then it starts to open debugger.
Apparently the dialog gets blocked but I don't have further ideas on what I can use instead.

My code is.

```
SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
save.FileName = tbl.Rows[0][0].ToString();

if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && save.FileName != "")
{
     FileStream FS1 = new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create);
     byte[] blob = (byte[])tbl.Rows[0][1];
     FS1.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
     FS1.Close();

     FS1 = null;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, `Dispose()` of your `FileStream`s.  Setting it to null doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: To extend on Ed, use a `using` statement to clean up your FileStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String FileName = tbl.Rows[0][0].ToString();
String FilePath = "C:/...."; //Replace this

System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
byte[] blob = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath );
response.BinaryWrite(blob );
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you get an error? This seems a decent solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using a Windows Forms SaveFileDialog in an ASP.NET website. This is not possible. Maybe it works on you development machine since the Cassini service is running as current user.

Solution:

Write something that works for ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

There is `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` and `HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite` and client browser should handle how to save it

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // 1.
    // Get path of byte file.
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Adobe2.png");

    // 2.
    // Get byte array of file.
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    // 3A.
    // Write byte array with BinaryWrite.
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);

    // 3B.
    // Write with OutputStream.Write [commented out]
    // Response.OutputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    // 4.
    // Set content type.
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    }
}
```

example from http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-binarywrite